# error: request for member ‘update’ in ‘ofEvents’, which is of non-class type ‘ofCoreEvents&()’|

Tags: c++, class, member, openframeworks

I have a C++ code written using OpenFrameWorks 007 pre-release and I'm modifying it to match OpenFrameWorks 008. The line -

`1. ofAddListener(ofEvents.update, this, &ofxAutoControlPanel::update);`
gives the error - 
    `src/ofxAutoControlPanel.h|9|error: request for member ‘update’ in ‘ofEvents’, which is of non-class type ‘ofCoreEvents&()`

which I am not able to decipher.

1. Changing `ofEvents.update` to `ofEvents->update` throws the same error
2. Changing `ofEvents.update` to `ofEvents().update` solves the issue

Can someone explain the differences among these 3 cases?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ofEvents is pointer to a function with type ofCoreEvents&(). That is a call of the function returns reference to an object of type ofCoreEvents that has data member update.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `ofEvents` class has been changed in OF 0071. 
Citing from the [changelog](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#of-0071):

> ofEvents -> ofEvents() singleton - this means that projects which register calls using "ofEvents." will need to replace these with "ofEvents()." (note the parentheses).

That's why your number 2 solution works.